# how to reindex ref column from sorting a date column?

Tags: postgresql

how can I reindex a ref column depending on content of a date type column ?

```
alter table ....
```

or the only method is to remove & recreate a new ref (primary key ...) column ?

thanks.

currently I have something like

```
REF|date      |....|....
------------------------
3  |2020-09-01|....|....
5  |2020-08-02|....|....
```

I want to update it as   (align sorting of dates & of REF)

```
REF|date      |....|....
------------------------
5  |2020-09-01|....|....
3  |2020-08-02|....|....
```

and so on for all that table

Comment: I don't understand what "a ref column depending on content of a date type column" is. Can you show the `CREATE` statements, so I know what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think of this not as shuffling but as updating row values. ie you don't change your primary key according to the data, you update your rows with new data. New data in this case is a sorted list of dates.

Is your `ref` column a serial / sequential integer primary key? If it is, you can generate row_numbers to match your primary key -

```sql
WITH sorted_dates AS
   (SELECT date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) FROM table)
UPDATE table
SET date = sorted_dates.date
FROM sorted_dates
WHERE table.id= sorted_dates.row_number
```

**Note**

If this is a live table, I don't recommend constantly shuffling your data.

- If you want to save a sorted list, you can index your date column.
- If you want a serial id sequentially tracking your date, you can simply generate a row_number dynamically.

Comment: The solution works perfectly with 2 little limits I had to remove a constraint & drop the index first  on ref column to adapt it to my needs . No the table isn't a live one so I can rearrange it.